# How to prevent redundant string conversion step when parsing with jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have some code that converts a restful response into a recursive structure. However, the content i want to parse into a tree is wrapped into a "treeprop" property. Is there a more convinient way to parse the real content?

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonFactory jfac = new JsonFactory();
JsonParser jp = jfac.createParser(inputStream);
JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(jp);

JsonNode path = rootNode.path("treeprop");
String realContent = mapper.writeValueAsString(path);

MyTree mt = mapper.readValue(realContent, MyTree.class);
inputStream.close();
```

Please note that parsing itself is not the problem here. The code above does convert the inputStream correctly into a tree. However, the json is larger than 1MB pretty often, so temporary storing it in a String cant be runtime efficient.

```
{
  "treeprop": {
    "id": 0,
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "children": [
          {
            "id": 3,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "id": 4,
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "children": []
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And the class looks roughly like this

```
class MyTree {
   public Integer id;
   public List<MyTree> children;
}
```

So the real question is: Is there an more efficient alternative te achieve the same:

```
JsonNode path = rootNode.path("treeprop");
String realContent = mapper.writeValueAsString(path);
MyTree mt = mapper.readValue(realContent, MyTree.class);
```

Comment: More information would be helpful here - first, a sample of the json input you're trying to parse; second - the MyTree class.

Comment: Take a look at this answer, I believe it will suite your needs. -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20635220/json-parser-for-recursive-structure/20635380#20635380

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MyTreeWrapper {
    private MyTree treeprop;

    // getter, setter
}

...

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyTreeWrapper wrapper = mapper.readValue(inputStream, MyTreeWrapper.class);
MyTree tree = wrapper.getTreeprop();
```

Alternative:

```
MyTree tree = mapper.reader(MyTree.class).readValue(rootNode.path("treeprop"));
```