# Jackson: JsonBackReference - infinite recursion problem

Tags: java, json, spring, serialization, jackson

My knowledge with JSON is limited so hopefully you can point me in the right direction.

I'm trying to post an object (Library) but this throws an exception due to infinite recursion

```
public class Library{
    private List<Book> books= new 
    ArrayList<Book>();
    //omitting rest of attributes, constructor, 
   and getter/setters
}

public class Book{
    private List<Author> authors= new 
    ArrayList<Author>();
    //omitting rest of attributes, constructor, 
    and getter/setters
}

public class Author{
    private Book book;
    //omitting rest of attributes, constructor, 
    and getter/setters
}
```

As you can see, this results in an infinite recursion that cannot be serialized:

```
Library -> Book -> Author -> Book -> Author...
```

This is poorly designed but I do not have the option to change the model.

I have tried to solve this making use of the `JsonManagedReference` and `JsonBackReference`.

```
public class Library{
    @JsonManagedReference(value="book")
    private List<Book> books= new 
    ArrayList<Book>();
    //omitting rest of attributes, constructor, 
   and getter/setters
}

public class Author{
    @JsonBackReference(value="book")
    private Book book;
    //omitting rest of attributes, constructor, 
    and getter/setters
}
```

However, this is not working and I get error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not handle
>   managed/back reference 'book': no back reference property found from
>   type [collection type; class java.util.List, contains [simple type,
>   class .......model.Book]]

I am able to serialize the object if I remove the `@JsonManagedReference`annotation and leave the `BackReference`. However, the serialized object sets `Book` instance in `Author` to null, resulting in an exception when attempting to persists this in the database.

Am I placing my annotations in the right place? Any suggestions?

**Edit:** As suggested in the responses, my annotations were wrongly placed. The following works to serialize the object but Author is losing the reference to Book

```
public class Book{
@JsonManagedReference
private List<Author> authors= new 
ArrayList<Author>();
}

public class Author{
@JsonBackReference
private Book book;
}
```

This resolves the issue of infinite recursion. However, I get SQL exception as cannot insert a null value.

```
Library -> Book -> Author X Book
```

author table contains a nun-nullable reference to the book.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45362300/java-hibernate-json-infinite-recursion-with-self-referencing-class/45362568#45362568

Comment: I think the the `@JsonManagedReference` needs to be on the `Book` class, and not on Library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your annotations in the wrong place.

Why the `Library` has `ManagedReference` for books while you're preventing recursion between `Author` and `Book`?

This is probably the way it supposed to be:

```
public class Author {
    @JsonBackReference
    private Book book;
}

public class Book {
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Author> authors = new ArrayList<Author>();
}
```

More over, there is definitely a wrong model that `Author` has one-to-one relationship with a book. Logically an `Author` may own many `books`.

Comment: The name of the classes were amended for clarity, but yes, I should have used a different example than Book/Author.

Comment: Your approach makes sense and I just tried it. Unfortunately I get same error. I will give it another try using the value parameter.

Comment: These annotations worked when placed the other way around: BackReference in Author and ManagedReference in Book. However, I'm getting an SQL exception when attempting to save to database. The issue is that, after serialization, Book (in author) is set to null. I'll update the question

Comment: @Fithos great, I edited my answer so it can be a proper guide to resolve the issue. But do not post many unrelated questions to one topic. If the issue resolved - accept the answer and post a new one. Doing this will increase your chances to get an answer.