# Serialization of @ManyToOne object with customized child object in JPA/Jackson

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have two entity classes with bidirectional `@OneToMany`/`@ManyToOne` relationship. When I do serialize `Class A`, I don't want to have whole `Class B` inside class A, only the id field. But, class B still needs to appear as an object inside class A and not just a property. How can I achieve that? I am using JPA:2.2/Jackson:2.9.0

```
@Entity
public class A {

    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private B b;

    // ...
}

@Entity
public class B {

    private long id;
    private String str;
    private boolean bool;

    @OneToMany
    Set<A> aList;
    // ...
}
```

Desired result of Class A:

```
{
    "id" : 123;
    "b" : {
        "id" : 321;
    }
}
```

Comment: did u tried using @JsonIgnore annotation? or u can simply remove A object inside B it will still have ManyToOne relation

Comment: @Mustahsan I want to be able to fetch/serialize Class B independently. Adding `@JsonIgnore` will be problematic because then I will never access those fields inside the object.(?) Json structure should be presented as in the question

Comment: add @JsonIgnore before  A's object

Comment: Right, but then I will not get `"b" : {
        "id" : 321;
    }` inside Class A, right?

Comment: you will get it inside A i am asking to add annotation before Declaration of object of A in class B before OneToMany

Comment: Can you please answer the question with code sample? For clarity :)

Comment: please check and let me know if it worked

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: @J-Alex No, it is not working as I wanted to. I want to have b as an object inside my json but nothing works like that. :(

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this:

1) Ignore properties:

```
@Entity
public class A {

    private long id;

    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"prop1", "prop2"})
    @ManyToOne
    private B b;
}
```

2) [JsonIdentityInfo](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIdentityInfo.html) and `PropertyGenerator`. Requires `id` property.

```
public class A {
   @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
   @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
   public B b; 

   public long id;
}
```

3) [JsonValue](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonValue.html) - indicates a single method/field that should be used to serialize the entire instance.

```
public class B {

    @JsonValue
    public long id;
}
```

4) Custom serializer:

```
@Entity
@JsonSerialize(using = ASerializer.class)
public class A {

    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private B b;

    // ...
}
```

You need to implement `ASerializer` in this case.

This is a not the easiest but flexible and a granular way of customisation of serialized objects.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44203990/dto-from-json-with-dynamic-key/44211090#44211090) example.

Comment: Hi @J-Alex , i have a few questions about option 2 and 3. Option 1 is no usefull because object has a lots of properties (more than 50). 

I did use option 2 in class B. Used  `@JsonIdentityInfo` in class level in Class B but it resulted the field I wanted in Class A was just a field and not a nested object.

About option 3, if I use `@JsonValue` on id field in Class B, does this mean that when I serialize Class B independent from Class A, still gonna get the whole object? Or just id in every case?

Comment: I tried to implement option 4 as well. I have a `Set<Element> mySet = ...` in my Class A and they have bidirectional (onetomany(Class A)/manytoone(Element)) relationship. When I serialize Class A, I get recursive problem. Any way to avoid it in my ASerializer class?

Comment: @Yonetmen in 3rd case it affects all serialization methods, independent serialization as well.

Comment: @Yonetmen regarding infinite recursion:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45362300/java-hibernate-json-infinite-recursion-with-self-referencing-class/45362568#45362568 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54217220/jackson-jsonbackreference-infinite-recursion-problem/54217466#54217466

Answer (score -1):

You can try use @JsonIgnoreProperties to ignore certain fields

```
@Entity
public class A {

    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private B b;

    // ...
}

@Entity
public class B {

    private long id;
    private String str;
    private boolean bool;

    @OneToMany
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"ignoreField1", "ignoreField2"})
    Set<A> aList;
    // ...
}
```